# Automation of testing graphs

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I'm trying to test the correctness of graphs generated by a web-application. Each graph could contain as many as 10,000 points plotted, whose values are on the website (in the form of a table) related to it. Again, when each point is hovered, it shows three different values (three columns of the table). I thought of selenium, but then realized I can't do it for all the 10K points. Is there any other approach I can use? I tried googling but didn't find any positive result.

PS- These are dynamically generated and the URL doesn't change.

EDIT:I'd ideally like to test a few random points out of the 10,000 records.

Comment: just to clarify you want to compare the values that show up when you hover over a point with the values in the table?

Comment: my other question is why would you test all 10,000 points? i would assume you could probably safely test it with only a handful of points

Comment: @Calum Yes, I want to compare the values that appear on hovering (if not all, a few random ones). Yes again, my bad, I should have mentioned that I need to test a few out of 10000 points.

Comment: in which case i dont see why selenium would not work. you should be able to accomplish this i imagine using the mouse hover?

Comment: @Calum That's a good point. 1. But I'd like it to be random things each time. 2. Before generating the graph, I get to pick one attribute, which again should be random. 3. I'm curious if there's any other way to do this other than Selenium. I'm not sure if the first 2 reasons make any sense but maybe 3rd one does (if it doesn't violate community guidelines)

Comment: if im understanding your question right then im sure there are plenty of tools that could do this including selenium, you just have to introduce a random function into the equation when selecting which points/attributes you want to test